# Unable to install Kubernetes on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-14.04

Using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty while installing Kubernetes, I am getting this error

> kubelet : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14ubuntu1 is to be installed

I copied

> deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main

package location in kubernetes.list and update.

I am new in Kubernetes.